# how to print the inner text of a promise using testcafe?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to do an assertion which prints out the text context of an alert banner. The banner is only visible if a user enters the incorrect login information. Here is the assertion:

```
await t
    .expect(login.alertMessage.exists)
    .notOk(
        "I don't see the user details page. I see this " +
        await login.alertMessage.innerText 

    );
```

The assertion would always pass if he enters the incorrect info.

If I do a negative test(meaning if the user enters the correct log in info) the assertion would fail on this line: `await login.alertMessage.innerText` and the error message is

**1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.**

If I remove the **await** in **await login.alertMessage.innerText** then the assertion doesn't show me the inner text of the banner. Instead, I see

**1) AssertionError: I don't see the user details page. I see this: {"_then":[],"_taskPromise":null}: expected true to be falsy**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter expression you are passing to the `.notOk()` function is always executed before the assertion is done by the expect statement.

This means that `await login.alertMessage.innerText` is always executed before the `expect` statement.

When the user enters correct login info, TestCafe will not find the alertMessage selector and will output the first error you have mentioned.

When you remove the `await` keyword, `selector.innerText` is a `Promise<string>`; concatenating this Promise with a string will call the toString() method on the  Promise but will not resolve the promise itself.

You should rewrite your expect statement like this :

```
const alertMessage = login.alertMessage;
if (await alertMessage.exists) {
    throw new Error(`user cannot login: ${await alertMessage.innerText}`);
}
```

But doing this you may face another problem: the alert popup my take some time to appear in the DOM and may appear after the if statement has executed and you will get a false positive test when the user cannot log in.

To prevent this you must implement your own waiting mechanism before entering the if statement. 
One solution is:

```
const alertMessage = login.alertMessage;
await t.wait(5000);
if (await alertMessage.exists) {
    throw new Error(`user cannot login: ${await alertMessage.innerText}`);
}
```

you could also replace the `await t.wait(5000)` with a more sophisticated approach as explained [here](https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-snippets#tc-wait-until-exists-property-of-selector-is-stable)